# Resource leak - too many device contexts

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7-x64

I have a (generally) working C++/Windows program which I noticed had a graphical resource leak. I the used [GDIView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/gdi_handles.html) and traced it to a build up of device contexts.

Looking further I tracked it to a pair of lines (see comments "Line A" & "Line B") as follows:

```
hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd,&global_paintstruct);

handle_of_source_device_context = CreateCompatibleDC(GetDC(0)); // Line A

#if 0 // temporarily while debugging
// stuff using handle_of_source_device_context
#endif

DeleteDC(handle_of_source_device_context); // Line B
EndPaint(hwnd,&global_paintstruct);
```

If I comment out lines A & B then there is no resource leak.

I tested that DeleteDC returns 1.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you have to release the handle returned by GetDC as well.

Comment: So you do. It's mentioned in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144871.aspx): "After painting with a common DC, the ReleaseDC function must be called to release the DC."

Comment: Also you can use WTL smart pointers: CClientDC and DC

Comment: Why are you calling `CreateCompatibleDC(GetDC(0))` anyway, as opposed to `CreateCompatibleDC(hdc)`?

Comment: @andlabs: cutting and pasting other people's code that I don't fully understand. Yup, just tried your version and that works fine :-)

Comment: Right. `GetDC(0)` returns a DC to the screen. When you want to do work with a compatible DC, you usually want to make it compatible to the DC that you're working with. In this case, `hdc` is the DC that you're likely going to draw onto, so make your DC compatible to that. If you're going to work with the screen DC, then you can make your DC compatible to that. (I don't know under what situations your code would break, but I would think DPI awareness is one of them.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call `ReleaseDC` for DC when it is no longer needed to prevent GDI leaks. The fixed version of your code will look like this:

```
hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd,&global_paintstruct);

HDC hWndDC = GetDC(NULL);
handle_of_source_device_context = CreateCompatibleDC(hWndDC); // Line A

#if 0 // temporarily while debugging
// stuff using handle_of_source_device_context
#endif

ReleaseDC(hWndDC);
ReleaseDC(handle_of_source_device_context);
DeleteDC(handle_of_source_device_context); // Line B
EndPaint(hwnd,&global_paintstruct);
```

Answer (score 2):

Call ReleaseDC on the return value of GetDC:

```
dc = GetDC(0)
...
ReleaseDC(dc);
```